# iOS - Display Twitter Accounts Stored On Device

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to display the names of the twitter accounts stored on the device of the user. Here is what i have tried:

```
        if (granted == YES) {

        NSArray *twitterAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        _accounts = twitterAccounts;

    }

      cell.textLabel.text = [_accounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It just doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `cell.textLabel.text = [_accounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`  :

```
ACAccount *account = [_accounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = account.username;
```

The `_accounts` array should be holding ACAccount instances. You can find some other properties here: [ACAccount Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ACAccount/username)